# immutable reducer in redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, redux

Is this reducer looks fine? why the author used a `let users;`, that look unnecessary to me. Isn't that will cause 2 users in FETCH_USER_FULLFILLED case?

```
const initalState = {
  users: [],
  loading: false,
  error: null,
};

// REDCUER
function usersReducer(state = initalState, action) {
  let users;
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'FETCH_USER_PENDING':
      return { ...state, loading: true };
    case 'FETCH_USER_FULFILLED':
      users = action.payload.data.results;
      return { ...state, loading: false, users };
    case 'FETCH_USER_REJECTED':
      return { ...state, loading: false, error: `${action.payload.message}` };
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

export default usersReducer;
```

Comment: users is unnecessary and I think so is the use of template literal `error: \`${action.payload.message}\``

Answer (score 0):

The reducer is fine and it will not cause two users in `FETCH_USER_FULLFILLED`. However, you are right, there is no need for `let users;`. So the code will look like

```
case 'FETCH_USER_FULFILLED':
  return { ...state, loading: false, users: action.payload.data.results };
```

When the reducer first executed, it will take its start state from `initalState` as it is the default if no param passed. So `users` will be empty array at the beginning and will be filled on `FETCH_USER_FULLFILLED` action

**Edit** `users` Added to take advantage of property [value shorthand](http://www.benmvp.com/learning-es6-enhanced-object-literals/) feature in ES6